# SelectOneMenu set to null when updating p:panelGrid

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am having a problem, I am firing a ajax event in a selectOneMenu like this: the first one does not fire any event

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="IdSelectOne" value="#{MB.myentity.myValue}" converter="myConverter1">
  .....
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="IdSelectTwo" converter="myConverter2">
    <p:ajax event="change"  process="@this" partialSubmit="true" 
       listener="#{MB.ChangeOption}" update="creatPanel" >
    </p:ajax>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The problem is that when the ajax event updates the panel, the first SelectOneMenu sets tu null, i can't use @form because it validates all fields and never do what I need which is show a field based on the selection of the second SelectOneMenu, is there a way to avoid this problem to happend?

This is my backing bean:

```
public void ChangeOption(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    .....  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sets to null"? do you mean that the selected value for the first dropdown is cleared?

Comment: Exactly, to the "Select an Option" value, (in my case is null) for this option, thanks

Comment: I don't see a `value` binding for `idSelectOne`. There's no reason for it remember what was selected, if there is no value binding there

Comment: It had, i didn't add it, already edited my question... thanks

Comment: You should use EL like `value="#{MB.myentity.myValue}"` instead of `value="MB.myentity.myValue"`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating just the element I needed and not the complete panel, Thanks